# why my elasticsearch search slow?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have the following mapping in ***elasticsearch5.5***:

```
"append": {
      "type": "short"
    },
    "comment": {
      "type": "text",
      "index": "analyzed"
    },
    "create_time": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "desc_score": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "goods_id": {
      "type": "long"
    },
    "goods_name": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    },
    "handler": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    },
    "is_first_review": {
      "type": "short"
    },
    "logistic_score": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "mall_id": {
      "type": "long"
    },
    "order_id": {
      "type": "long"
    },
    "order_sn": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    },
    "parent_id": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    },
    "review_id": {
      "type": "long"
    },
    "score": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "service_score": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "shipping_id": {
      "type": "long"
    },
    "shipping_name": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    },
    "status": {
      "type": "short"
    },
    "tracking_number": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    },
    "update_time": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "user_id": {
      "type": "long"
    }
```

When I profile in kibana with the following statement and got the result in the picture.

```
    {
      "from": 0,
      "size": 10,
      "query": {
      "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "goods_id": [
              "262628158"
            ],
            "boost": 1.0
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "status": [
              "2",
              "4"
            ],
            "boost": 1.0
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "create_time": {
              "from": "1514027649",
              "to": "1514632449",
              "include_lower": true,
              "include_upper": true,
              "boost": 1.0
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "disable_coord": false,
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1.0
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "create_time": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

I am confused why `status` filter cost so much time,  and `status` is a field with only five value, this is perpahps the reason cause the problem but I do not know how to optimize my search clause. I have search a lot with google but got no answer yet. Any one can help me?

Comment: What I do notice is that you map the status field as a short and you filter it like a string. Would not expect that to be the issue, but it is also not logical. The other thing I notice is that you sort on a date field. How many documents do you have within the range you specified? Can you try it with a smaller range? Could be that the sorting is the problem.

Comment: @JettroCoenradie Thanks for your response. I tried `status` 2 and 4, but also the same result. My cluster has 1.5 billion documents and I also removed sort but got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I find the answer, it is because `elasticsearch5.5` use kd-tree to store index data for numeric data type(short, long, etc.) for optimize range search which can be found in following article:

[Better Query Planning For Range Queries](https://www.elastic.co/blog/better-query-planning-for-range-queries-in-elasticsearch)

[Tune For Search Speed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-search-speed.html#_map_identifiers_as_literal_keyword_literal)

[Elasticsearch Query Execution Order](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-query-execution-order)

Kd-tree is not suitable for exact term, and I changed the filed type to `keyword`.